# How to customize QListWidget background color (and not QListWidgetItem)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I wonder if there is a way to customize QListWidget background color.

I have tried:

```
listWidget=QtGui.QListWidget()
listWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
p = listWidget.palette()
p.setColor(listWidget.backgroundRole(), QtGui.QColor("#424242"))
listWidget.setPalette(p)
```

While there were no errors it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a stylesheet that changes the background:

```
self.setStyleSheet( """QListWidget{
                    background: yellow;
                }
                """
)
```

Example output:

[image: SS]